# terraform resource s3 upload file is not updated

Tags: terraform

I am using terraform to upload a file with contents to s3.However, when the content changes, I need to update the s3 file as well. But since the state file stores that the s3 upload was completed, it doesn't upload a new file.

```
resource "local_file" "timestamp" {
  filename = "timestamp"
  content = "${timestamp()}"
}


resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "upload" {
 bucket = "bucket"
 key = "date"
 source = "timestamp"
}
```

expected:

aws_s3_bucket_object change detected
aws_s3_bucket_object.timestamp Creating...

result:

aws_s3_bucket_object Refreshing state...

Comment: I can't reproduce this at all. Is this the entirety of what you're trying to do? I see the `id` and `content` changing which causes a `forces new resource` replacement update.

Comment: it forces new file creation but not the s3 upload

Answer (score 16):

When you give Terraform the path to a file rather than the direct content to upload, it is the name of the file that decides whether the resource needs to be updated, rather than the file's contents.

For a short piece of data as shown in your example, the easiest solution is to specify the data directly in the resource configuration:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "upload" {
 bucket  = "bucket"
 key     = "date"
 content = "${timestamp()}"
}
```

If your file is actually too large to reasonably load into a string variable, or if it contains raw binary data that cannot be loaded into a string, you can set the `etag` of the object to an MD5 hash of the content so that the provider can see when the content has changed:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "upload" {
 bucket  = "bucket"
 key     = "date"
 source  = "${path.module}/timestamp"
 etag    = "${filemd5("${path.module}/timestamp")}"
}
```

By setting the `etag`, any change to the content of the file will cause this hash result to change and thus allow the provider to detect that the object needs to be updated.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work for buckets with kms encryption

Comment: I believe you could use `content = file(FILENAME)` instead of `source`.

Comment: Replace ```etag    = "${filemd5("${path.module}/timestamp")}"```  with ```etag    = filemd5("${path.module}/timestamp")``` because Interpolation-only expressions are deprecated

Comment: I think you can use `source_hash = filemd5("path/to/source")` for encrypted files.